# A question on Kronecker Index

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

I am reading A book by Milnor (Lectures on characteristic classes) and I can across this section on Stiefel-Whitney numbers (page 16) and he uses the Kronecker index but never defines it (He says to look on page 118 in Lefschetz Algebraic Topology but then he uses some $\beta$ function and says this is from earlier but I can't find it, so that didn't help).  Could someone give me the definition he is using?  He defines the fundamental class with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z_2}$ and calls this $\mu$.  I understand that part I think.  But he doesn't define Kronecker index = $<?, \mu>$.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I just figured this out.  Thanks.

Comment: Congratulations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean the subsection about Stiefel-Whitney numbers. The Kronecker index is nothing more than evaluation! I.e. the evaluation map $H^n(M;\mathbb Z/2) \otimes H_n(M; \mathbb Z/2) \to \mathbb Z/2$ (or rather: induced by the evaluation map on chain level).

You can look at elements $x_i$ in the cohomology ring of the compact manifold, which live in the top cohomology after multiplying(cupping) them all together and consider their kronecker index $\langle x_1 \cup \cdots \cup x_k  , \mu \rangle$. This leads to the definition of Stiefel Whitney numbers.

Comment: But how is the mapping actually defined?  (The evaluation)

Comment: Actually I get it now.

Comment: on chain level you have homomorphisms on simplices (which may be singular, simplicial, cellular), which means you can evaluate them to get something like $C^n \otimes C_n \to \mathbb Z/2$. Then one checks that this induces a map when passing to homology.