# What is the $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ operator when calculating Stiefel-Whitney numbers?

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-k-theory

I've been trying to understand Stiefel-Whitney numbers and I'm reading [this paper](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2017/REUPapers/Malaney.pdf). On page 9, the author defines the Stiefel-Whitney number using an operator $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. I've tried to look in other places too, but I can't see it defined anywhere. There is an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936964/a-question-on-kronecker-index) but it seems to boil down to "it is the evaluation map" and I'm not sure what htat means. Can someone help me with a direct definition/formula for this (even in just the case of CW-complexes)?

Comment: Just to add to the correct answer by @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, the only thing you need to check is well-definedness. That is, if you choose two representatives and evaluate separately, you should (and will) get the same result. A quick overview of Stiefel-Whitney numbers, together with a detailed explanation of the evaluation map can be found in *Characteristic Classes* by Milnor and Stasheff.

Comment: Thank you both! I did go thorough Milnor and Stasheff in some detail now and it makes sense to me. If either of you would like to put your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

A cohomology class is represented by a cocycle, which is in particular a cochain, ie a function on chains. A cocyle by definition takes the value $0$ on boundaries, and choosing a different representative, ie changing the cocycle by a coboundary, doesn't change this function on cycles. Therefore a cohomology class $\alpha \in H^k(X, R)$ defines a linear map $H_k(X, R) \to R$. This map is often written $\sigma \mapsto \langle \alpha, \sigma \rangle$. As $\alpha$ varies, you get a (linear) map $H^k(X, R) \to \operatorname{Hom}(H_k(X, R), R)$ and if $R$ is a field (plus maybe some finite generation assumptions), this is an isomorphism.